# linear regression simpson's paradox

Tags: regression, paradoxes

I need advice on this problem. It is related to Simpson's Paradox.

Consider three binary variables $X, Y, Z$ and all taking values in $\{0, 1\}.$

Consider the following inequalities:

$P(X = 1) > P(Y = 1)\tag 1$

$P(X = 1 \land Z = 1) < P(Y = 1 \land Z = 1)\tag 2$

$P(X = 1 \land Z = 0) < P(Y = 1 \land Z = 0) \tag 3$

Assumed all inequalities, (1) (2) and (3), are true, which of the following claims are true?:

a) If I perform a linear regression of X on Z, the $e^Z$ must be negative.

b) If I perform a linear regression of Y on Z, the $e^Z$ must be positive.

c) If I perform a linear regression of X − Y on Z.  the $e^Z$ must be negative.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Comment: What is "e ect"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The question makes no sense:
$P(X=1\wedge Z=0)+P(X=1\wedge Z=1)=P(X=1)$
$P(Y=1\wedge Z=0)+P(Y=1\wedge Z=1)=P(Y=1)$
So if $P(X=1\wedge Z=0)<P(Y=1\wedge Z=0)$ and $P(X=1\wedge Z=1)<P(Y=1\wedge Z=1)$ then how is it possible to have $P(X=1)>P(Y=1)$?